# How to run Selenium test from Netbeans

Tags: java, testing, netbeans, selenium

I have built a test case in the Selenium IDE. 
Now, how can I most simply implement the test case to run from Netbeans?

My Netbeans version is 7.2. Selenium server is running in my Netbeans services.
This is my simple test case for a Google search. I have tried to export as a Java/Junit file. Netbeans shows the class path missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.google.co.in/" />
<title>google_search</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">google_search</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>selenium</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a New java project in your IDE.

Download the Selenium Standalone server [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list.)

Put the jar file in the lib and Start to create your Selenium test cases.

If you want to run it on Chrome then download the `chromedriver.exe` file [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)

For to run on IE download the `IEDriverServer.exe` for respective bit version [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

**Sample code:**

```
 WebDriver driver  = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("URL");
 //Do some actions
 driver.quit();
```